# jQuery datepicker: manual firing of onChangeMonthYear()

Tags: jquery, methods, datepicker

I've this function:

```
$('#picker').datepicker({
    // ...
    onSelect: function(currDate){

    }
});
```

I want to fire the function `onSelect()` manually, but `$('#picker').datepicker.onSelect();` doesn't work. How to fire it?

Comment: Is the datepicker initialized (as in "you can see it on the webpage")?

Comment: What do you mean be fire the function manuell? Do you want to catch the event or override the onSelect method?

Comment: Yes, the datepicker is initialized. 

I want to set the date manually: $('#..').datepicker('setDate', ..); I thought the onSelect handler() was fired their too but it wasn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the callback function by doing `datepicker("option","onSelect")`. I set up an example of how you can use it here: http://jsfiddle.net/KjquJ/